# How to reload a DataGrid in Flash ActionScript after an XML file has loaded?

Tags: flash, actionscript, datagrid, actionscript-2, rowcount

Is it possible to change the `RowCount` of a `DataGrid` in flash after it has been created on the stage?

I am loading an XML file externally that contains the number of rows the `DataGrid` should have, but the problem is that because this file is not loaded at runtime, it just picks the default 3 items. Maybe I have to reload the `DataGrid` on the stage, or loop until it is defined.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: DataGrid inherits the [`rowCount`](http://help.adobe.com/nl_NL/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/2/help.html?content=00002578.html#3149569) property from the List component. Set this property with the value you want after loading the XML. Also make sure the component has the height large enough to display the number of rows you want (which you can do with `setSize()`). In case the update doesn't take place immediately you can force it by using `invalidate()`. As long as your Data grid instance on stage has an instance name you should be able to control it from actionscript 2

Answer (score 0):

Are we talking Flash or Flex? If we're talking Flex you can actually just use DataBinding. Just place the [Bindable] attribute above the variable that contains your XML and when you update your variable with new data, the grid will be updated too.

If you really do mean Flash, then I've got no clue.

Answer (score 0):

**Flex Project:**

Use bindable to force updates when dataprovider changes.

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        [Bindable]
        private var _loadedXMLData : XML; // load xml and store here
    ]]>
</fx:Script>


<mx:DataGrid dataProvider="{_loadedXMLData}" width="100%" height="100%"/>
```

---

**Flash project:**

Be sure to set the data provider when the XML has been loaded. If it does not give you the correct amount of rows, try this:

```
// set flash datagrid component rows manually
dg.rowCount = 10;
```